# Why am I getting plotly express attribute error? (AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_hline'

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code that is mostly copy/pasted form the plotly website.  I get an attribute error code with the line "fig.add_hline(y=0.9)". Why do I get this error?

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.express as px

print("plotly version: ", py.__version__)

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_hline(y=0.9)
fig.add_vrect(x0=0.9, x1=2)
fig.show()
```

**Output:**

plotly version:  4.8.2

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_hline'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Horizontal and vertical lines and rectangles](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/) are [introduced in plotly 4.12](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-12-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-and-rectangles/46783).
You're on `4.8.2` so you'll have to run an [update](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/).